# How convert String to Date in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have string as `06/08/2013` that I want to convert into Date Object

I do

```
var transactionDate = Date.parse(transactionDateAsString);
```

and I get `NaN`

How can I tell javascript to format the string as `dd/mm/yyyy`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-string-to-date-in-js

Comment: Check out [Date.js](http://www.datejs.com/)

Comment: Duplicate of all of these: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+date+parse+string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Break it down and spoon-feed it:

```
var parts = transactionDateAsString.split("/");
var date = new Date(parts[2],parts[1]-1,parts[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Date.parse()` from the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse):

> Parses a string representation of a date, and returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC.

You probably want to use the `Date` constructor:

```
var transactionDate = new Date(transactionDateAsString);
```

Comment: That makes it `Sat Jun 08 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)` which is incorrect. It should be `August 06`

Comment: @daydreamer: The native parse functions use the American format `MM/DD/YYYY`. At least it's consistent across browsers.